# how could i change URL in text widget contents using mysql?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-widgets

I have sidebar to place text widgets in my word press website, now i tried to move from local server to another one, i have used more than 20 text widgets and placed contents, images on that, now i need help for update the URL on text widgets content.

I need to change 192.168.1.211/wordpress to 192.105.112.210/anbo,

kindly help me

Answer (score 2):

Please Try [WP Migrate DB](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) Plugin, hopefully It should solve your problem.